# How to create oracle view based on comparing value of table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have to create a oracle view based on a table which like following:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td><td>store-id</td><td>prod-id</td><td>s-date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>21</td><td>2</td><td>NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>21</td><td>3</td><td>12-12-16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>22</td><td>2</td><td>NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>22</td><td>3</td><td>NULL</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td><td>23</td><td>4</td><td>12-12-16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td><td>23</td><td>5</td><td>12-12-16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

now in view i have to add new column called status, which is bases on s-date value for store-id, if one store has all s-date null then status = 0
if store has all s-date not null then starus = 2 and if a store has not all null s-date then status =1, so view look like following:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td><td>store-id</td><td>prod-id</td><td>s-date</td><td>status</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>21</td><td>2</td><td>NULL</td><td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>21</td><td>3</td><td>12-12-16</td><td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td><td>22</td><td>2</td><td>NULL</td><td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td><td>22</td><td>3</td><td>NULL</td><td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td><td>23</td><td>4</td><td>12-12-16</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td><td>23</td><td>5</td><td>12-12-16</td><td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you actually need? Is that HTML table an object (BLOB/CLOB) you receive from front-end application? Do you want to create a view parsing that HTML table? Since you tagged `plsql`, maybe you'd like to create a procedure / function parsing the table?

Comment: I think the HTML part is only for showing us how the user wants the data.

Comment: yes your are right Nitish, HTML table is for showing data how user want.

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted the data of first four columns into a table `STORE_DATA`.

```
SELECT A.*, TAB1.STATUS
  FROM STORE_DATA A,
       (SELECT T.STORE_ID, COUNT(T.S_DATE) STATUS
          FROM STORE_DATA T
         GROUP BY T.STORE_ID) TAB1
 WHERE A.STORE_ID = TAB1.STORE_ID;
```

`Count` of a particular column will only return the non null values.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on your data.

```
CREATE TABLE stores  
(  
   ID NUMBER(2),  
   store_id NUMBER(3),  
   proc_id NUMBER(3),  
   s_date DATE  
);  

INSERT INTO stores VALUES(1,21,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO stores VALUES(2,21,3,TRUNC(SYSDATE));
INSERT INTO stores VALUES(3,22,2,NULL);
INSERT INTO stores VALUES(4,22,3,NULL);
INSERT INTO stores VALUES(5,23,4,TRUNC(SYSDATE));
INSERT INTO stores VALUES(6,23,5,TRUNC(SYSDATE));  
COMMIT;
```

You can use create below view.

```
CREATE VIEW stores_view  
AS  
SELECT s.id,  
       s.store_id,  
       s.proc_id,  
       s.s_date,  
       (CASE  
         WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1)     
                 FROM stores s1    
                WHERE s1.store_id = s.store_id    
                  AND s1.s_date IS NOT NULL) = 0 THEN   
              0  
         WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1)     
                 FROM stores s1    
                WHERE s1.store_id = s.store_id    
                  AND s1.s_date IS NULL) = 0 THEN    
              2    
         ELSE    
              1    
       END) status  
  FROM stores s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your reply:

I have solve this issue like following:

First I created a function to calculate status like following:

```
FUNCTION CALC_STATUS(s_date_count IN NUMBER, store_count  IN NUMBER)RETURN NUMBER
AS
  n_status NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF s_date_count = 0 THEN
    n_status     := 0;
    RETURN n_status;
  END IF;
  IF s_date_count < store_count THEN
    n_status     := 1;
    RETURN n_status;
  END IF;
  IF s_date_count = store_count THEN
    n_status     := 2;
    RETURN n_status;
  END IF;
END CALC_STATUS;
```

then user above function to create a view :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_SRORE (ID, STORE_ID, PROD_ID, S_DATE, STATUS)
                      AS
  SELECT A.ID         AS ID,
    A.STORE_ID        AS STORE_ID,
    A.PROD_ID         AS PROD_ID,
    A.S_DATE          AS S_DATE,
    TEMP_TABLE.STATUS AS STATUS
  FROM T_STORE A,
    (SELECT B.STORE_ID,
      CALC_STATUS(COUNT(B.S_DATE), COUNT(B.STORE_ID)) AS STATUS
    FROM T_STORE B
    GROUP BY B.STORE_ID
    ) TEMP_TABLE
  WHERE A.STORE_ID=TEMP_TABLE.STORE_ID
  ORDER BY A.STORE_ID DESC;
```